# How to not overwrite array when using array_replace_recursive

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using the array_replace_recursive to merge two arrays in laravel controller

```
            $sub = collect($getsubject)->toArray();
            $ter = collect($getterm)->toArray();
         
          }
       
        $report=array_replace_recursive($sub,$ter);
```

this works well except that the  key or index 0 is replaced by the index 0 of the other array. How can i have the same merging behavior without the overwriting of data of the arrays where the key is similar?

Comment: Did you tried `array_merge`?

Comment: Indexed arrays will be "ignorantly" replaced.  If you want to respect associative replacements, then you'll need to replace indexes with **non-numeric** associative keys.  It will probably be a good idea to include sample data and your desired output in your question via an [edit] as part of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since you use laravel's collection class, have you tried using ["merge()"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) helper function?

Given from laravel's documentation : *"The merge method merges the given array or collection with the original collection. If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given items's value will overwrite the value in the original collection:" [...] **If the given items's keys are numeric, the values will be appended to the end of the collection:***

You could do something like so :

```
$sub = collect($getsubject);

$report= $sub->merge(collect($getterm));

$report->all(); //displays the final result
```

More infos [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge).